# how to play rtsp url in android?

Tags: android, rtsp

how to play rtsp url in android ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use either `MediaPlayer` or `VideoView` for this,it will not work in emulator

you can do like

```
mediaplayer.setDataSource(String RTSP);   //  if you are using mediaplayer
```

or

```
videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("rtsp://...../file"));   // if you are using videoview
```

both methods u can tryout

Comment: That's because that link is invalid.

Comment: What about RTP/UDP ?! I'm using this https://github.com/Elbandi/droidtv , And can't play