# RTSP Stream in VideoView in Android Application

Tags: android, video, streaming, rtsp, playback

I am trying to write a very simple application which simply tries to playback a video which is being streamed by a RTSP Server. 
I had read somewhere that the VideoView component is capable of handling RTSP Streams.
So i have written the code in the following way.

```
vv = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
    mc = new MediaController(getApplicationContext());
    vv.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(url));
    vv.setMediaController(mc);
    vv.requestFocus();

    vv.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {

        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            vv.start();

        }
    });
```

The URL String is of the following format 
rtsp://192.168.1.136:8554/mercykilling.mkv

My problem is that i keep getting an error as below

V/MediaPlayer(16501): message received msg=100, ext 1=1, ext2=-18

Can anyone give any pointers on this topic?

Answer (score 2):

previous [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4898774/how-to-play-rtsp-url-in-android)

previous [background](http://boardreader.com/thread/Android_2_3_4_0_rtsp_video_streaming_err_oy3hwX5mt6u.html)

General Comment - RTSP / RTP supports the inclusion of a very large set of underlying encodings and specs for packing media track inside packets and im not sure that the standard Android libStageFright libs actually support it in all of its permutations.

I looked at the ICS samples in the sdk under API / media / video...

ApiDemos\src\com\example\android\apis\media\MediaPlayerDemo_Video.java

take a look at your SDK and at the comments in the above sample...

```
        case STREAM_VIDEO:
            /*
             * TODO: Set path variable to progressive streamable mp4 or
             * 3gpp format URL. Http protocol should be used.
             * Mediaplayer can only play "progressive streamable
             * contents" which basically means: 1. the movie atom has to
             * precede all the media data atoms. 2. The clip has to be
             * reasonably interleaved.
             * 
             */
```

Those comments do **NOT** support the idea that android 4.0 mediaPlayer will play RTSP streams.

If you want to test a generic RTSP stream, i would suggest that you grab a feed from Youtube and try to play the URL for the format=1 stream , which will be RTSP protocol. 
Example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8716146/rtsp-youtube-link)

Answer (score 0):

mkv only supports from version 4.0+ 
[Take a look](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html)

And one thing always keep in your mind is that to support rtsp streaming, you have to start rtsp server. Otherwise you can't start that file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the library @ http://net7mma.codeplex.com/ (Of which I am the author)

It can provide an easy way to allow playback of `Rtsp` or `Rtp` media in Android.