# Android: Play RTSP video from URL

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer, android-video-player

I'm trying to play an RTSP url in my android app, using the following code:

```
String url = "rtsp://mobilestr1.livestream.com/livestreamiphone/nyc";
                    Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
                    System.out.println("URL="+url);
                    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri));
```

However an alert dialog pops up after a few seconds saying "Unable to play video".
I have tried several RTSP urls and none of them work. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4898774/how-to-play-rtsp-url-in-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That stream is h264 MPEG-4 AVC Part 10.  Which doesnt work on most android devices. 
This page has a list of what does work. But essentially you need an MPEG-4 Baseline stream.

http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html#recommendations

If you open the stream in VLC and then :
Window > Media Information > Codec Details you can verify this info as well

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code. It works for me. Don't forget to add internet permission in your manifest.

```
private void rtspStream(String rtspUrl) {
    mVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(rtspUrl));
    mVideoView.requestFocus();
    mVideoView.start();
}
```